# Listing all open workbooks except Current within combobox vba

Tags: combobox, except

I am currently using this code to list all open workbooks within a combobox, but I don't need the source workbook to be listed as well.

```
Dim wkb as Workbook
With Me.ComboBox1
For each wkb In Application.Workbooks
.Additem wkb.name
Next wkb
End with
```

Tried .removeitem 0
But it identifies source workbook as item 0, only if it has been opened before all other workbooks.